# Adding blocks in Magento's Checkout 'Review' stage

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm building an extension to add a specific block right before the 'Place Order' button in Magento's Onepage checkout. I'm having some trouble finding the right incantations to simply append a block to this section, much less get it before/after another handle. The object is to engage this override without any template changes.

In my extension's XML, I have:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="myextension/blockname" name="myextension.block" template="myextension/block.phtml" before="checkout.onepage.review.button" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

myextension/block.phtml is, for now, just a simple block of text. I know the general syntax is correct, as I'm able to add my <block> to checkout_cart_index and see it just fine.
Am I missing something basic?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the usage of the word "incantations"

Comment: checkout Vinai's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9225198/219986

Comment: I've read it, but that doesn't necessarily provide a definitive answer, as the linked post is in regards to adminhtml. But I suppose it could provide a workable (if not a bit messy with the incurred overhead) alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Background

Not all blocks output their children blocks automatically. Only blocks of the `core/text_list` type and templates where `echo $this->getChildHtml()` (no arguments)  s called.
Children of template blocks are rendered by a call to `echo $this->getChildHtml('child_alias')`.
It makes sense if you think about it - children of template blocks need to be positioned somewhere in the context of the template HTML.
Referring to your question, there is no functional difference between the layout handles `checkout_onepage_review` and `checkout_cart_index` besides them referring to different pages.

### Adding content to the checkout review

The checkout review block contains two `core/text_list` children to whom you can add children using layout XML that will automatically be displayed.

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before">
        <block type="core/text" name="review.test.1">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>Test Block Before</text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
        <block type="core/text" name="review.test.2">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>Test Block After</text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

The only problem is that the `checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after` block is rendered before the agreements block, so in your case it might not be good enough.
The agreements are rendered with this code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
    <li>
        <div class="agreement-content"<?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>
            <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_a->getContent())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <p class="agree">
            <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" class="checkbox" /><label for="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></label>
        </p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

If you want to add a block after the agreements, right before the "Place Order" button, without changing the template, and without rewriting the agreements block, you can try to add an additional item to the end of the `checkout/agreements` collection, having `is_html` set to true, and your output as the `content`.
This turns out to be problematic, though, because the agreements model, resource, and collection don't offer a custom event prefix.

What this boils down to, if the provided `checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after` block doesn't work, are the following options. Each one is ugly in it's own way, so the choice of the smallest evil is yours:

- Observe the `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` mentioned in the post linked to in the comments
- Observe the `core_collection_abstract_load_before` event and add a html agreement on the fly
- Rewrite the `checkout/agreements` block and overload the `_toHtml()` method

My recommendation would be to somehow make use of the `checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after` block - that solution would be so much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Vinai. However, this doesn't explain how this is any different from checkout.xml, which I'm able to update with no problems. Shouldn't all layouts be created equal, so to speak? What's so magically different between <checkout_onepage_review> and <checkout_cart_index>?

Comment: Your layout declarations should go into a module layout XML file, **not the checkout.xml file**. The difference between the layout handles `checkout_onepage_review` and `checkout_cart_index` is that one is processed during the review step of the onepage checkout, the other is processed on the shopping cart page. I don't understand what you are getting at I guess.

Comment: Of course. I realize they're go in my extension layout, that's where they are. :) What I'm asking in my question is why you're suggesting a specific workaround for `checkout_onepage_review`, when I had no problems with a layout update using `checkout_cart_index`. Is there an actual documented reason why `checkout_onepage_review` needs to be treated differently, or are you simply offering a workaround (which I appreciate) because you aren't sure why it doesn't work the way it should?

Comment: If I read the question right (just re-read it to be sure), you want to affect a change at the bottom of the review block on the onepage checkout page. These comments of yours are the first time the `checkout_cart_index` page (or handle) are mentioned. Do you want the change on the cart page then (in contrast to your original question)?

Comment: Correct on my mission (your first sentence). However, `checkout_cart_index` was definitely mentioned in my original question (though not formatted), but my goal isn't to affect that handle, I'm simply providing it an example of a layout update that Just Works(TM). So at the moment my question is why I'm able to set the same layout update on `checkout_cart_index` and get output, but not with `checkout_onepage_review` - it's a layout file, it should work the same way, yes?

Comment: OK, now I think I understand what you are asking. The difference is in the parent block type. Some blocks output all child blocks automatically, e.g. `core/text_list` blocks or `echo $this->getChildHtml()` (with no arguments) in templates. This is not the case in the review block, so you have to look for a block that fulfills this criteria, e.g. the `checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after` block. Regular `core/template` based blocks don't automatically render all children.

Comment: That's quite inconvenient. However, `checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after` worked well enough for me, so I can mark your response as an answer. Just out of curiosity, though, do you have any documentation that supports this on Magento's site? Seems like an awfully misleading thing to not have spelled out somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: I can only refer you to the source, i.e. `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getChildHtml()` and `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::_toHtml()`. With template blocks, child blocks are rendered using `echo $this->getChildHtml('alias')` in the template file, which makes sense, because they need to be positioned within the context of the template.