# Magento Admin Sales > Order > Item Url

Tags: url-rewriting, magento-1.5, magento

I am trying to create a link from my helpdesk software to the sales order page in the backend of magento.

Magento constructs the url as the example below where the number represents the Order ID.

/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/**12394**/

However, the Order Id does not equal the Order Number because credit invoices etc. are included in the count.

Is there an other way for me to link to the order page using the Order Number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 types of order number in magento

1. Order increment id
2. Order id (mostly use internal in magento).

The admin uses the order id while the number on you invoice is the order increment id.

The quickest way to get around this is to create a custom module that look up order id by order increment id and the redirect to the view page using the order id.

In /app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_OrderRedirect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_OrderRedirect>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MageIgniter_OrderRedirect>
  </modules>
</config>
```

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/OrderRedirect/controllers/RedirectOrderController.php

```
<?php

class MageIgniter_OrderRedirect_RedirectOrderController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function viewAction(){

       $increment_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
       $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
       $order_id = $order->getId();

       Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=> $order_id)));
    }
 }
```

in In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/OrderRedirect/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_OrderRedirect>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageIgniter_OrderRedirect>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <orderredirect>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MageIgniter_OrderRedirect</module>
                <frontName>orderredirect</frontName>
            </args>
        </orderredirect>
    </routers>
 </frontend>   
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <orderredirect>
        <class>MageIgniter_OrderRedirect_Helper</class>
      </orderredirect>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

url

> www.site.com/orderredirect/redirectOrder/view/id/101512486

Comment: args/modules, not args/module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, but how would I use the order redirect in practice, is there a certain url that I need to use?

Comment: site.com/index.php/admin/redirectorder/view/id/12394/ (where 12394 is the order increment id, the order # shown on a invoice)

Comment: Hi R.S!

I get a 404, the module is visible in system > configuration > advanced.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a url that rewrites the order id to the order increment id and forwards to /index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/12394/ where 12394 is the order increment id.

Comment: I just test and update the code above and it does work now, I made a lot of changes so it's best if you just delete previous and start over (should be controllers not controller folder)

Comment: Thanks! Works great, would it be possible to have the redirect url in after /admin instead of in the frontend?

Comment: I dont think it would work in all cases (eg. if you have 'url key' enable for you admin url). That how I was doing originally in my previous example

Comment: Hi R.S. I enjoy using the order redirect extension. I am thinking of putting an input field on the dashboard that redirects in the same way to the order view page. Our invoice have a barcode and this would allow use a barcode scanner to go to the order page.

I don't know how to use your function, which is writter as a router, to work with the input of a input field.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218970/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-a-custom-dashboard-box-in-the-magento-backend-wi .. then you could use JS onchange to redirect